# Elastic search Query String in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch in my application to search for a matching word anywhere in a table.

This is the query string i have used to fetch my result:

```
search({ query: { prefix: { _all:  keywords }}, sort: [ { start_date: 'asc', start_time: 'asc' } ] })
```

The selected records were then being queried with the dates to match the date range(s) specified in the application, by the following query:

```
where("status_id= ? and active=? and (((start_date >= ?) and (start_date <= ?))
or ((start_date <= ?) and (? <= end_date)))",2,true,range_start_date,
range_end_date,range_start_date,range_start_date)
```

But i know this is not a good way to fetch results. Now i want to modify this to fetch just the required data from elasticsearch index.

After a long search i found "query_string" and "simple_query_string" to match my requirement. But i am unsuccessful till now to get the required result.

How can i append the query with the elasticsearch result to get the required records? 
Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i was able to find the answer for the question myself. I was able to filter the searched content according to date with a "filter" keyword.

I modified the query as:

```
search_query = {
 query: {
   prefix: { 
     _all:  keywords 
   }
 }, 
 filter: {
   query: {
     query_string: {
       query: "status_id:2 AND active:true AND 
       ((start_date:>=#{range_start_date} AND start_date:<=#{range_end_date}) (start_date:<=#{range_start_date} AND end_date:>=#{range_start_date}))"
     }
   }
 },
 sort: [ { start_date: 'asc', start_time: 'asc' } ] }
```

And finally fetched the result by:

```
@result = self.search(search_query)
```

If there is anyway i could modify this code, please suggest. Thank You.